How can I make time zones consistent on R shiny plots and sliders?
I am working on a little R shiny app that generates graphs based on user inputs. I first made a plotting function and it works as intended, where the x-axis is fixed for a range of time. The idea is to then have user parameters add lines/ribbons/annotations.
When I use this app on the shiny dashboard, however, it displays an incorrect time on the ggplot's x-axis (although the time on the input sliders is correct). I noticed, that if I change my computer's timezone from mountain time to UK/Greenwich time, that fixes the dashboard plot.
But if I try to set a timezone at the start of the code with something like Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC'), it fixes the plot and messes up the sliders' time...
I also tried specifying the timezone every time I use as.POSIXct() to make it consistent but no luck either.
Can't seem to find a way to have both sliders and plot on a consistent time zone. Any suggestions?
Here is a simpler and reproducible version of my code:
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# plotting function
plot_fc <- function(window_start, window_end){
  
  plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_ribbon(data = data.frame(time = c(as.POSIXct(window_start, format = "%I:%M %p"), as.POSIXct(window_end, format = "%I:%M %p"))), aes(x = time, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "orange", alpha = 0.5) + 
    ylim(-8, 12) +
    xlim(as.POSIXct("3:00 PM", format = "%I:%M %p"), as.POSIXct("11:59 PM", format = "%I:%M %p"))
  
  return(plot)
  
}

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("window", "window start and end",
                  min = as.POSIXct("3:00 PM", format = "%I:%M %p"),
                  max = as.POSIXct("11:59 PM", format = "%I:%M %p"),
                  value = c(as.POSIXct("5:30 PM", format = "%I:%M %p"), as.POSIXct("8:00 PM", format = "%I:%M %p")),
                  step = 60,
                  timeFormat = "%I:%M %p")),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))))

# server 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({plot_fc(input$window[1],input$window[2])})
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Thanks in advance!

Can you respond whether the answer works? What is the point of the edit?

Just replied to your answer below, thanks for taking some time! I just added a screenshot on my edit to show how the dashboard looks on my end.

Use tz = "UTC" inside the as.POSIXct for the values, the min and max of the sliderInput and also pass timezone = "UTC":
sliderInput(
  "window",
  "window start and end",
  min = as.POSIXct("3:00 PM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC"),
  max = as.POSIXct("11:59 PM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC"),
  value = c(
    as.POSIXct("5:30 PM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC"),
    as.POSIXct("8:00 PM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC")
  ),
  step = 60,
  timeFormat = "%I:%M %p",
  timezone = "UTC"
)



That's closer! I see the sliders and plot consistent but it displays from 1pm to 10pm. Is there a way to make them both display 3pm-midnight? That's the time that I set on slider input and plotting function

@Nacho Yes, please see my updated answer. You need tz = "UTC" also in min and max.
